# Django Identify file pattern

Tags: django

I am implementing a way to restrict file upload on Django 1.8 running Python 3.4.

Basically, I want to check the MIME type of a file when they upload using `mimetypes`. However, when I manipulate the file name from `bad_image.exe` to `bad_image.exe.jpg`, the MIME type is still `image/jpeg`. This could still result in a malicious attack.

Is there a way to actually implement this?

Comment: I edited your question, but still I don't understand the logic behind a complaint, that when you change from `.exe` to `.jpg`, it is still `image/jpg`... I think you need to clarify what you do and what are your expectations.

Comment: So i simply renamed a `.exe` file to a `.jpg` file, for example `bad_code.exe` is renamed to `bad_code.exe.pdf`. I want to correctly identify the extension of this file.

Comment: There might not be a single correct extension. Files can be polyglot documents, i.e. multiple formats at the same time. And then interpretation depends on the context. See https://events.ccc.de/congress/2014/Fahrplan/system/attachments/2562/original/Funky_File_Formats.pdf for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially perform the check in reverse by setting a blacklist of MIME types to prohibit. Then, for each of these MIME types, use e.g.

```
mimetypes.guess_all_extensions('application/x-msdownload')
```

to yield a list of possibly malicious extensions, which you can then search for in the uploaded filenames.

**Warning.**

Relying on filenames and MIME types to defend against malicious uploads is [not safe practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7506/using-file-extension-and-mime-type-as-output-by-file-i-b-combination-to-dete). At the very least, sandboxing user uploads in a separate domain prevents any malicious code that slips through your defenses from attacking your site.